# How can I debug "Error: Expected a backslash preceding the semicolon"?

Tags: vite, postcss

I have been working on this project for a while and this error never happened to me. I did some changes, removed the changes and went back in the commit history. The error is still there no matter what version I use.

The error happens when I run "vite dev" or "vite build" (via "npm run dev" or "npm run build").

I am running Vite in Laravel 9.

Here's the problematic file according to the console:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@media print {
    body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .print {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

The error goes away when I remove the first three lines.

How can I find the "bad" line of code and fix it?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.4",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.6",
        "vite": "^2.9.11"
    }
}
```

And here is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
};
```

Comment: can you say which plugin you use ? Maybe sharing your package.json and/or `vite.config.js`.

Comment: @flydev It's done!

Comment: You dont have a file `postcss.config.js` ? I post it as answer with instructions and try it please.

Comment: @flydev Sorry, forgot to add it! It's there :)

Comment: I suggest you to publish a reproducible project. I tested it with the same versions found in your package and it's working. Let us know.

Comment: @flydev To be honest, it's really weird. It works on some previous commits where I didn't change anything. Will try to do this and let you know.

Comment: I see.  What's your node and npm version ? You could also try to remove `package-lock.json`, the `node_modules` folder and installing it again to see what happen.

Comment: Finally, it was a file that contained wrong CSS. Tailwind compiled it in app.css and it caused the error. It was persisting throughout the versions because of some cache issues.